# How do I dynamically set the height of a UICollectionViewCell to fit a bunch of text while keeping a fixed width?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a collection view that can display a vertical list of cells (so 1 column) where each individual cell's height is sized to fit some variable text. This means that the width of my cell is fixed to the bounds of my collection view (I think?). Each cell contains a UILabel for the text.

I know it's easy to do this with a Table View, but ultimately I want my list to be able to jump between a grid-style and a list-style with the tap of a button. I figured a single collection view could handle both cases.

It's pretty easy to get the cell to shape itself to the label using UIFlowLayout, but I haven't been able to fix the width. I've tried mucking around in `collectionView(sizeForItemAt)`, and I can get the width right but here I'm not sure how to get the dynamic height.

If I can't figure this out then I'll just use a table view AND a collection view.

UPDATE:

I've made a small bit of progress since posting. By setting flow layout to estimated size, I was able to get the dynamic height I wanted. Within my `collectionView(cellforItemAt indexPath)` I was able to get the maximum width to the bounds of my collectionView by doing the following: `cell.textPreview.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = collectionView.bounds.width - 10`. [But anything less than the max and my cell will stay small enough to fit the label.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r9xt.png) So now I need to figure out how to fix my label's width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda hack-y, but I solved my own problem. Here's what I did:

I created a special UICollectionViewCell within a Xib for the sole purpose of sizing my text. This cell only contains a label. I set the constraints on my sizing cell such that the width was fixed to the bounds of my collection view.

```
func getDimensions(for text: String) -> CGSize {
    if let cell = SizingTextCollectionViewCell.fromNib() {
        cell.configure(with: text)
        cell.textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = collectionView!.bounds.width
        cell.labelWidthLayoutConstraint.constant = collectionView!.bounds.width
        return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }
    return CGSize.zero
}
```

Then in `collectionView(sizeForItem)` (out of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`) I return the size of each cell given some text. And now it works! [This guide was really helpful.](https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel/)